# How to convert Flow<List<Object>> to Flow<Object> Kotlin coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given an `ObjectA` that contains a `List` of `ObjectB` from a `WebClient` request. I'm wanting to return a flow of my `DTO` from `ObjectB`

```kotlin
data class MyDto(val id: String, val name: String) {
 companion object {
   fun from(objectB: ObjectB) {
      return MyDto(id = objectB.id, name = objectB.name)
   }
 }

...
return webClient.get()
   .uri(baseUrl)
   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToFlow<ObjectA>()
   .flatMapConcat { response ->
      val x = response.objectB.map { MyDto.from(it) }
      retrun@flatMapConcat flowOf(x)
   }
```

This returns JSON of `Array<Array<MyDto>>`

```json
[
 [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Joe"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Jane"
  }
 ]
]
```

Expected results are `Flow<MyDto>`

```json
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Joe"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jane"
 }
]
```

Comment: Did you mean to write retrun?

Comment: Yes, it complains if I don't do the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flowOf(x)` returns `Flow<List<ObjectA>>`, but you need to return `Flow<ObjectA>`

```
...
.flatMapConcat { response ->
      response.objectB.asFlow().map { MyDto.from(it) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I definitely need to do more reading up on coroutines, it's fairly new to me.