# How to create a list from scanned BLE results

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

as invers to the question asked here [How to convert `Flow<List<Object>>` to `Flow<Object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67168734/7095974) I want to convert my `Flow<Object>` to `Flow<List<Object>>`.

At least I think I want that, so I try to explain what I want to achieve and give some background. I am working on an Android application that uses bluetooth to scan and connect to BLE devices. I'm fairly new to the Android platform and kotlin so I haven't quite grasped all the details despite all the many things I've already learnt.

My repository has a method which returns a Flow of ScanResults from the bluetooth adapter:

```
fun bluetoothScan(): Flow<ScanResult> {
    return bluetoothStack.bluetoothScan()
}
```

My ViewModel consumes that function, maps the data to my BleScanResult and returns it as LiveData.

```
val scanResults: LiveData<BleScanResult> =
    scanEnabled.flatMapLatest { doScan ->
        if (doScan) {
            repository.bluetoothScan().map { BleScanResult(it.device.name, it.device.address) }
        } else {
            emptyFlow()
        }
    }.asLiveData()
```

In my activity I want to observer on that data and display it in a RecyclerView:

```
val adapter = ScanResultListAdapter()
binding.rcBleScanResults.adapter = adapter

viewModel.scanResults.observe(this) { result ->
    //result.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
}
```

The problem is that `scanResults` is from type `Flow<BleScanResult>` and not `Flow<List<BleScanResult>>`, so the call to `adapter.submitList(it)` throws an error as `it` is expected to be a list.

So, how do I convert `Flow` to `Flow<List>` (with additional filtering of duplicates)? Or is there something I  miss about the conception of Flow/LiveData?

Comment: `So, how do I convert Flow to Flow<List>` having a list with one item in most likely isn't going to help you, so i'm not sure that's what you really want, you need an actual list with several entries

Comment: Do you want each flow emission to add something to the list displayed in RecyclerView?

Comment: That's true, but how about this: The `Flow<ScanResult>` of the repo gives the current scan result element. In the ViewModel, scanResults data type changes to `scanResults: LiveData<List<BleScanResult>>` and the ViewModel transforms `ScanResult` to `BleScanResult` and adds it to `List<BleScanResult>` if it destinct from other items in the list. How about that? How can I do that?

Comment: @bylazy Yes, exactly

Comment: i've updated your question to make it a bit more relevant, feel free to change it

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a `MutableList` and fill it with the data you get form a `Flow`, something like the following:

```
val results: MutableList<BleScanResult> = mutableListOf()
val scanResults: LiveData<List<BleScanResult>> =
    scanEnabled.flatMapLatest { doScan ->
        if (doScan) {
            repository.bluetoothScan().map { 
                results.apply { 
                    add(BleScanResult(it.device.name, it.device.address)) 
                } 
            }
        } else {
            emptyFlow()
        }
    }.asLiveData()
```

You can also use a `MutableSet` instead of `MutableList` if you want to have a unique list of items (assuming `BleScanResult` is a `data` class).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `liveData` builder to collect the Flow's values into a MutableList.

Here I copy the MutableList using `toList()` before emitting it since RecyclerView Adapters don't play well with mutable data sources.

```
val scanResults: LiveData<List<BleScanResult>> = liveData {
    val cumulativeResults = mutableListOf<BleScanResult>()

    scanEnabled.flatMapLatest { doScan ->
        if (doScan) {
            repository.bluetoothScan().map { BleScanResult(it.device.name, it.device.address) }
        } else {
            emptyFlow()
        }
    }.collect {
        cumulativeResults += it
        emit(cumulativeResults.toList())
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicate entries and reordering of entries, you can use a set like this:

```
val scanResults: LiveData<List<BleScanResult>> = liveData {
    val cumulativeResults = mutableSetOf<BleScanResult>()

    scanEnabled.flatMapLatest { doScan ->
        if (doScan) {
            repository.bluetoothScan().map { BleScanResult(it.device.name, it.device.address) }
        } else {
            emptyFlow()
        }
    }.collect {
        if (it !in cumulativeResults) {
            cumulativeResults += it
            emit(cumulativeResults.toList())
        }
    }
}
```